# Pulling Next Event with Events Calendar & Ajax Load More

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am editing a site that is using Ajax Load More to pull in info from the Events Calendar plugin. The client wishes for this area to pull the next post, instead of whatever past event it is pulling right now and I could use some help.

This is the site: https://milfordpa.us/ and the section is the one for schoolhouse days.

This is the content within the Repeater Template of the ALM plugin:

```
// Ensure the global $post variable is in scope
global $post;
 
// Retrieve the next upcoming events
$events = tribe_get_events( [ 'posts_per_page' => 1 ] );
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $event->ID ), 'full' );
 
// Loop through the events: set up each one as
// the current post then use template tags to
// display the title and content
foreach ( $events as $post ) {
   setup_postdata( $post );
 ?>

<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
<?php endif;
}

?>
<div class="featured-event" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <?php
   // This time, let's throw in an event-specific
   // template tag to show the date after the title!
   echo '<h2>' . $post->post_title . '</h2>';
   echo '<p> ' . tribe_get_start_date( $post ) . '</p> ';
?>
      <div class="fusion-button-wrapper">
        <style type="text/css">
          .fusion-button.button-3 {
            border-radius: 0px;
          }
        </style><a class="fusion-button button-flat fusion-button-default-size button-default fusion-button-default-span fusion-button-default-type" target="_self" href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link() ?>"><span class="fusion-button-text">Learn More</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: change line about tribe_get_events function to:

```
$events = tribe_get_events( [
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'start_date'     => 'now',
] );
```